# how to change ZooKeeper ensemble

Tags: hive, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I want to access hbase using hive 2.1.1 ,I use the command:
 hive -hiveconf hive.root.logger=DEBUG,console hbase.master=node131:16000

Then I try to create table:

```
CREATE TABLE iteblog(key int, value string) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" =":key,cf1:val") TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "iteblog", "hbase.mapred.output.outputtable" = "iteblog");
```

I found log:
INFO [main] zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Process identifier=hconnection-0x7cf63b9a connecting to ZooKeeper ensemble=**192.168.156.24**:2181 .
but I don't config 192.168.156.24 in hive or hadoop, I don't know why it show up .where can I find this config or change it?
I install hive in **192.168.156.25** and node131 is where hbase was installed.

Comment: Did you open `/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml`? You should find interesting stuff in there, especially `hbase.zookeeper.quorum` (which gets defaulted to your **local host name** + port 2181 by the HBase client, when not present)

Comment: Be aware that the `hbase.master` prop is pretty useless nowadays, because HBase client will contact ZK to get the active Master automatically (in case you have 2 in active/passive HA).

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter , do you mean hbase-site.xml in node131? node131   is where hbase was installed by someone else ,they use HDP 2.5, and I found "HBase Master Port" 16000 in ambari, its hbase.zookeeper.quorum is "node131,node132,node133"

Answer (score 0):

192.168.156.24's problem has been solved, I find the config in an old hbase installation,but this time it always connect localhost . Neither -hiveconf hbase.master nor hbase.zookeeper.quorum can change its behavior . I'll create another new post.